# Going from event editor back to calendar creates blacked out area near bottom

Tags: calendarkit

I've encountered this problem both in my own CalendarKit app as well as the sample app found [here](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit). The issue is that when I click on an event and enter the EKEventViewController and then navigate back, the calendar now looks like this:[image: Before][image: After]. Looking at the view hierarchy, it looks like the TimelineView has been truncated at the bottom a little. Any idea on what's going on/how to fix? Thanks.

I tried using present instead of pushing navigation controller, but then the "Delete Event" button on the bottom of the EKEventViewController just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in EventKitUI framework projecting itself onto the other ViewControllers. To fix it, add this line to `CalendarViewController`:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
```

This will solve your issue.